# Should we have tags for questions about getting a pet?

Tags: discussion, tags

We seem to get a steady input of "what kind of dog should I get?" questions, and I think it would be nice to have a tag for those, since they're kind of a more broad question, reliant on the owner's situation. I think it'd be nice to be able to sort through those easily.

Since there are a couple similar questions, like "how to tell if breeds of rabbits will have growth defects", and "what age should a snake be when you get it", I think a tag called [pet-selection](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pet-selection) would be nice.

Basically, [pet-selection](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pet-selection) would include anything in the process before getting a pet. Getting advice on choosing between different species/breeds, finding out what special care the animals might need, finding out if they're the right animal for them, etc.

Good idea/Bad idea?

Comment: What are the odds that newcomer would tag with that though? I may be overthinking it, but we'd want to be sure that it's one that people would actually select or we'll be constantly tagging for them.

Comment: I think the odds are pretty high, especially if we add synonyms for purchasing/picking/choosing. If a person is asking about getting a new pet, they'll probably type picking or choosing, and then the tag would pop up.

Comment: I would suggest Pet-Selection is more natural sounding, but that's just me. :) My hesitation, in any event, has been around it not appearing naturally. However, we're a community site, so don't let my hesitation hold you back. If it's useful, people will use it.

Comment: I like that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a great idea. While I'm normally only interested in questions with a dogs tag I would likely also look at questions with a selecting-pet type of tag as well.

Comment: I agree, and if we synonymize words that people use often, like suggested in the comments, I think it could also be helpful.